# List menu that open hidden views in it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I need to create a list menu where each item, when selected, will open a sub area with others controls (see the example image):

[image: Example layout image]

I have two possible solutions in my mind:

- Have all the item's controls in *RelativeLayout* with "gone" visibility, and list them in a *LinearLayout*.
- Use the *ExpandableListView*, but I have no experience with that and I don't know if this might be a proper solution in my case.

What do you think would be more elegant? Do you have other/better solutions?

Comment: Expandable list do exactly what you want. Look that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534885/android-expandable-list . I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ListView as well as ExpandableListView  to achive  your requirent.

[image]

[image]

I have done some thing by using ListView and slide animation that suits your requirement.
For Complete reference go through my Android blog

http://amitandroid.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-listview-with-animation.html

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Both approach would work but `ExpandableListView` should be better performance-wise.

You must provide a [`ExpandableListAdpater`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html), with a layout for your group item and another for the subitems.

Comment: Can I have a different layout for each subitems?

Comment: Yes, you can inflate a different layout depending on some properties. This should be done in the adapter `getView()` method